# How to add custom header to ASP.NET Core Web API response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am porting my API from Web API 2 to ASP.NET Core Web API.  I used to be able to add a custom header in the following manner:

```
  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", count.ToString());
  return ResponseMessage(response);
```

How does one add a custom header in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Comment: refer 3 ways to add a custom header in asp.net core https://codepedia.info/add-custom-header-aspnet-core-response

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can just hi-jack the `HttpContext` from the incoming Http `Request` and add your own custom headers to the `Response` object before calling return.

If you want your custom header to persist and be added in all API requests across multiple controllers, you should then consider making a `Middleware` component that does this for you and then add it in the Http Request Pipeline in **Startup.cs**

```
public IActionResult SendResponse()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", "20");

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: in order to get the added value in fetch api u need to write this after
```fetch(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('X-Total-Count'));
    return response.text();
})```

Answer (score 52):

For anyone who want to add custom header to all requests, middleware is the best way.
make some change in startup.cs like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Developed-By", "Your Name");
   await next.Invoke();
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: Modifying response directly in middleware is discouraged see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder-1). Instead you can use `context.Response.OnStarting` callback.

Comment: This did not work in my middleware which captures exceptions. The `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` would remove my header. Solution below by @Mojtaba works.

Comment: @BoukeVersteegh
This certainly did not work in the specific circumstances you tested. The problem is not the solution

Comment: @Mojtaba, there is nothing wrong and discouraged about modifying the response directly in the middleware. The documentation actually provides examples of doing so. But it should be done before calling `next`. The warning is only about that point: the response should not be modified after calling `next`.

Comment: @Frédéric You are right. I adjusted my answer below to reflect your note.

Answer (score 51):

There is an example for simple `GET` action which returns top `X` records from some list as well as the `count` in the response header `X-Total-Count`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("values/{top}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int top)
        {
            // Generate dummy values
            var list = Enumerable.Range(0, DateTime.Now.Second)
                                 .Select(i => $"Value {i}")
                                 .ToList();
            list.Reverse();

            var result = new ObjectResult(list.Take(top))
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
            };

            Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", list.Count.ToString());

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

URL looks like `http://localhost:3377/api/values/5` and results (for 19 dummy records generated, so `X-Total-Count` value will be 19) are like:

```
["Value 18","Value 17","Value 16","Value 15","Value 14"]
```

Comment: It feels hacky because we are basically setting the result and then  properties on it in 2 places.  It could be encapsulated in a custom action result. As I am typing I am just about to create an ContentResultWithHeaders. But having said that,  it feels like a lot of effort.

Comment: The base class [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-2.1) already includes the property `Response`.  Therefore, instead of calling `Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers` it's possible to simply call `Response.Headers`.

Answer (score 24):

A custom attribute can be a good way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
public class AddHeaderAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _value;

    public AddHeaderAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(_name, new string[] { _value });
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this on your API method

```
[AddHeader("X-MyHeader", "123")]
```

If you have a common header you can just extend this class :

```
public class MySpecialHeaderAttribute : AddHeaderAttribute
{
    public MySpecialHeaderAttribute() : base("X-MyHeader", "true")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant approach! Thank you so much. The attribute can also be applied to a Controller class. In my case, I created a SafeControllerBase which inherits from ControllerBase and attached the attribute(s) as needed. Now I am inheriting all controllers from SafeControllerBase, so the desired response is included to all responses.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with @Ho3Ein that

> if you want to add a custom header to all requests, middleware is the best way

but modifying `Resposne` directly in middleware (after calling `next.Invoke()`) is discouraged. From Microsoft [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder-1).

> Changes to HttpResponse after the response has started, throw an exception. For example, changes such as setting headers and a status code throw an exception.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
            await next.Invoke();
            // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
        });
```

So the better way to add a custom header in middleware is to use `Response.OnStarting` callback like below:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                      {

                          context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
                              {
                                  context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Developed-By", "Your Name");
                                  return Task.FromResult(0);
                              });

                          await next();
                      }
                      );
```

Comment: Looks nice, but how can I pass there the count of returned records from request?

Comment: This is a wrong interpretation of the Microsoft documentation. The documentation only warns against touching the response after having executed the continuation `next`. Changing it before is fine.

Comment: @Frédéric well, two things here. First, in the context of this question, i.e., adding a custom header, the documentation explicitly gives a warning. Second, for example, what change do you want to do before calling `next.Invoke()`?

Comment: The warning is only against changing the response after calling `next`. Do add your header before calling `next`.  Like in this other [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-7.0#server-side-and-prerendered-client-side-scenarios).

Comment: @Frédéric You are right. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Other middleware might clear out headers after you set them. To make sure your headers are added, add them just before the response is sent.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Response.OnStarting(() => {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Developed-By", "Your Name");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });

    await next();
});
```

Or in a real middleware

```cs
public class AddHeadersMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() => {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Developed-By", "Your Name");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        await next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is OK but if you want to add AES-like encoded values on headers you will get an Error:

> Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header

One way to pass is encoding the value one more time with URL encoding. To do it:

```
string urlEncodedValue = WebUtility.UrlEncode(value);
```

Vice versa to decode it:

```
string value = WebUtility.UrlDecode(urlEncodedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if you have an `ApiController`, instead of a `Controller`, here is how you can do it:

```
public class InfoController : ApiController
{
    // Without custom header
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(..)
    {
        var myObject= GetMyResult();
        return Ok(myObject);
    }

    // With custom header
    public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(..)
    {
        var myObject = GetMyResult();

        // inspired from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation#how-content-negotiation-works
        var negotiator = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
        var result = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(TypeOfMyObject), Request, Configuration.Formatters);
        var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<TypeOfMyObject>(myObject, result.Formatter,result.MediaType.MediaType)
        };

        msg.Headers.Add("MyCustomHeader", "MyCustomHeaderValue");
        return ResponseMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: ApiController is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim.dll which is a temporary solution to ease migration from asp.net 4.x to asp.net core. for new code i would not use ApiController.