# How to change charset of Response Header of ASP.NET Core Web API response?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc

I added a response header with reference to this following page:
[How to add custom header to ASP.NET Core Web API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183171/how-to-add-custom-header-to-asp-net-core-web-api-response)

I wrote:

```
 ObjectResult result = new ObjectResult("aaa");
 Request.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=shift_jis";
 Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("IPAddress", "10.11.12.13");
 Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("name", "Naoki");
```

I'd like to change the charset not only Response Body, but also Response Header. For example, "Naoki" and "10.11.12.13".Because double-byte characters are inserted in production data in Response Header.

How to change the charset in Response Header?
Best Regards.

Comment: I don't think you can alter the charset of the header https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4

Comment: Also ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header

Comment: Dear Frode, Thank you for your answering and information! I could understand of this.